# How can I import Landslide CRM data into Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I'm importing some customer information from Landslide CRM into Salesforce.
Anyone have advice on the best methodology for doing the import?

It seems like the Apex Data Loader is the best way to go, but I don't know
if there are any issues with handling the objects in question, or if there
might be a specific tool or script to perform this migration.

Any experience with this import in specific or importing data into Salesforce
in general would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing Data to salesforce can be achieved in multiple ways depending on the type of data nd the requirements you have.

The first thing to do is get your data into CSV files so you'll need to find a way to export the dat afirst. For UTF-8  encoded data don't use Excel use something like OpenOffice (only required if you have UTF-8 Characters)

If its account and contact data for example. There is an import wizard available in Setup > Administration Setup > Import Business Accounts/Contacts

Next Option is as you say to use the Apex Data Loader. This probably the best approach.

The first thing and this is critical for big migrations is to Create a Field on your account object which will be a Unique Field for reference purposes. When creating this field set it as an External ID field and populate it with a unique reference for your accounts, the same goes for anything else which will be a parent. (you'll see why shortly.)

Next use the Insert option in the Data Loader to load the data mapping all the fields, especially the External Id

Now when you upload child objects use the Upsert option and map your Account Id via the External Id created earlier. This will match the accounts using your unique Id instead of you having to use the Salesforce id, saves alot of time.

Repeat the same for other objects and you should be good to go.

Apologies for the lack for structure here... doing this while in work and don't have alot of time but hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The data loader works great for most types of imports. The one suggestion I would give you is to create a new custom field on your target objects (presumably Account and Contact) called "Landslide ID" or similar, identify it as an external ID field, and then import the primary keys from your source system into this field (along with the "real" data).

Doing this achieves a couple things - first, you have an easy unique link back to the source data for troubleshooting or tracing back to the source system. Second, if you find yourself in a situation where you need to import more fields or related data from the original source system, you'll be able to do so in an easy and correct way. It's just a good standard practice to adopt when doing data migrations -- it's almost no additional effort and can save you many hours in the future.

Comment: Here's a followup to this - any recommendation on importing Opportunities?  My main issue here is that i'm using the data loader, i'm mapping fields, but in my source data, there are Account Names (no id), and in the target data, there is an AccountID.  Is there any method that I can use to help map these, either during or after an import?

Comment: If your account names are unique, you can load that data into a new custom External ID field on Account, and then use that field as the foreign key in your opportunity import. The data loader can use external ID fields in lieu of actual SF ID's.